# Go to the given URL (if we not there), show the form and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this piece of code where the form is hidden until I click on the  element. If I'm in that page (profile.php) it shows the form and scrolls down to it but if I'm not on that page (e.g: index.php) it goes to thatpage(profile.php) but doesn't show the form and doesn't scroll down to it until I click again on that  element (which it is in the menu)
So here is my html code:

```
<a id='showForm'>Apply</a>
<div class="formL" style="display:none">
    //code
</div>
```

and here's my script:

```
<script>
        $('#showForm').click(function() {
            
            let currentURL = $(location).attr("href");
            let redirectURL = "http://127.0.0.1/dealaim/profile.php#formL"
            if (currentURL !== redirectURL) {
                $(location).attr("href", redirectURL);
                var formL = $('.formL').show();
                document.documentElement.scrollTop = formL[0].offsetTop;
            } else {
                var formL = $('.formL').show(); 
                document.documentElement.scrollTop = formL[0].offsetTop;
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code after your redirect won't do anything; that code needs to run on the page you redirect to, not the page doing the redirect.

Once the redirect takes place, it's a question of passing along some info that the page can receive and use to automatically invoke the function. So:

```
$('#showForm').click(function() {
        
    let currentURL = location.href;
    let redirectURL = "http://127.0.0.1/dealaim/profile.php?showForm=1"
    if (currentURL !== redirectURL)
        location = redirectURL;
    else {
        let formL = $('.formL').show(); 
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = formL[0].offsetTop;
    }
});
if (location.href.includes('showForm=1') $('#showForm').click();
```

Note also there's no point at all in doing `$(location).attr('href')` - you just unnecessarily invoke jQuery and wrap what is a simple object-and-property combo in its API. Just use `location.href`.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, it's like I click on the APPLY but stays where it is and do/change nothing

Comment: You're saying the redirect doesn't happen? Does the callback even fire?

Comment: yes the redirect doesn't happen. I guess callback doesn't fire too.

Comment: Don't guess; you just need to do some basic debugging. If the callback doesn't fire at all then you have issues outside the scope of this question. That suggests the event isn't firing, which suggests the selector isn't finding the element.